# How to sudo su; then run command

Tags: bash, sudo, pm2

Can anyone help me to to solve following issue

i need to ssh to another server by e.g. `ubuntu` user which has permission to run sudo su *fore sure* then execute pm2 restart command

full command look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD="sudo su; pm2 restart 0; pm2 restart 1; exit;"  
ssh -i somepemfile.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1 $CMD
```

for example i can run normally any command with sudo

```
CMD="sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart"
```

but with `sudo su` case it somehow hang and do not response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have an unusual setup, you can't normally string `su` with other preceding commands like that. I would imagine it is running `sudo su`, then hanging in the root environment/session, because it's waiting for you to exit before preceding to the `pm2` commands. Instead, I would consider something along the lines of this using the `-c` option:

```
CMD="sudo su -c 'pm2 restart 0; pm2 restart 1'"
ssh -i somepemfile.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1 "$CMD"
```

As suggested in another answer, it would also probably be useful to encapsulate the `$CMD` variable in quotes in the `ssh` call.

Answer (score 3):

su normally puts you in a sub shell which you can see by echoing the current PID (process id)

```
$ echo $$
94260
$ sudo echo $$
94260
$ sudo su
$ echo $$
94271
```

But to get around this you can pipe the commands you want to run to su like this

```
$ echo "whoami" | sudo su
root
```

And we run multiple commands

```
$ echo "uptime;whoami" | sudo su
11:29  up 8 days, 19:20, 4 users, load averages: 4.55 2.96 2.65
root
```

Now to make this work with ssh

```
$ ssh wderezin@localhost 'echo "uptime;whoami" | sudo su'
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Darn it, we need allocate a tty for the su command.  Add the -t option which allocates a TTY during the remote execution.

```
$ ssh -t wderezin@localhost 'echo "uptime;whoami" | sudo su'
11:36  up 8 days, 19:26, 5 users, load averages: 2.97 2.97 2.76
root
```

Your command would look this

```
ssh -i somepemfile.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1 'echo "pm2 restart 0; pm2 restart1" | sudo su'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-c` option of `su` to specify the command

From `man su`

> In particular, an argument of -c will cause the next argument to be treated as a command by most command interpreters. The command will be executed by the shell specified in
>          /etc/passwd for the target user.

```
CMD="sudo su -c  \"pm2 restart 0; pm2 restart 1;\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the expansion so that the entire string is parsed on the remote end.

```
ssh -i somepemfile.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1 "$CMD"
```

Otherwise, the expansion is subject to word splitting, and the remote shell gets a string which consists of the command `sudo` and the arguments `su;`, `restart`, `0;`, `pm2`, `restart;`, `1;`, and `exit;`. That is, `ssh` will escape the semicolons when it builds a single string from the separate arguments you pass.

However, that doesn't solve the problem of running `pm2` in the shell started by `sudo`. That is addressed by [ramki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527286/1126841).